# Can any body tell me how to open a FIle with .dat extension in cent os?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my new Ruby on rails application I want to find the users country code. 
So I am using MaxMind GeoIp. when I downloaded the gzip file after gunzip it gives me a GeoIP.dat file and I am stuck here. Can any one help. 
If their is a program to open it or some procedure to use it.
Or if any one can suggest me the other way.

Comment: Try using the [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command to find out exactly what type of file it is, and go from there.

Comment: @Satya Vi open the file but didn't show the actual data.

Comment: @x1a4 File command didn't work with it too.. but thanks for immediate response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Kyle pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293308/416630), you can download "human-readable" CSV files instead of binary DAT files.  MaxMind's "GeoLite" downloads are [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite).

[The CSV file format is described here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csv).

But note (from the link above):

> Due to the large size of geolocation databases, we generally recommend using our binary format with one of our APIs, since they are highly optimized for speed and disk space. On the other hand, if you have a requirement to import the data into a SQL database, the CSV format is recommended.

The [APIs are listed here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable).  There is no Javascript API listed, but there are a couple of options for Ruby.

So to answer your question directly:  You would not "open" the dat file directly as you would a spreadsheet document.  Instead you would write your own program that uses their API to read the dat file, and perform whatever tasks or queries you design it to do.  Check out their API documentation for details of how you might get started with that.

Answer (score 1):

`.dat` is just a file extension. The contents could be anything. Text. Binary data etc...

There is no way anyone could reliably tell you how to *open* the file.

I would attempt to view the contents of the file from the command line:

```
less file_name.dat
```

You can open the file and read line by line in ruby like this:

```
IO.readlines('file_name.dat').each do |line|
  # do something with the line
end
```

**Edit:** I think I found the file you're refering to. Why not go [here](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/) and download a `csv` version? The `.dat` version is not in plain text.